# Kotlin Coroutines :: "Best Practice" for ignoring Subsequent coroutine calls

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am investigating the use of Channels in my current Android project.

My viewModel has the following method:

```
private val completed: CompletableDeferred<Reaction<NetworkResponse>> = CompletableDeferred()
private val mutex = Mutex()

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun perform(action: Action): ReceiveChannel<Reaction<NetworkResponse>> =
    produce {
        if (mutex.isLocked) cancel()

        if (completed.isCompleted) {
            send(completed.getCompleted())
        } else {
            mutex.withLock {
                repository.perform(action).also { reaction ->
                    completed.complete(reaction)
                    send(reaction)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used the `mutex` and `CompletableDeferred` to ensure I only call out to the Network once.

Is this a valid approach?

Is there a better way to achieve my desired result?

Comment: You haven't managed to ensure anything here, it's the typical "check-then-act" fallacy. Any number of concurrent coroutines calling `perform` can reach `mutex.withLock`. You need double-checked locking where you re-check the `completed` status inside `withLock`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks, I spotted my basic error once I had posted my question. sorry for wasting your time

Comment: I'm also confused by the mismatch between the global scope of `completed` and the local scope of `action` it applies to. You can't call this function with more than one kind of action.

Comment: I am in an experimental phase with of my application, so theres much to be refactored, however Action is a sealed class with multiple values contained in its hierarchy, I do need a better solution for the single completed variable though

Comment: I think you should attach a `val result = async(start = LAZY)` to each of these actions. This gives you lazy evaluation out of the box.